# Creating menu of "n" sub menus in CSS

Tags: html, css, web, menu

I am trying to create a horizontal menu bar that when you hover over it, it drops down a list of submenus.  I also want these submenus to be able to contain any number of submenus.  Does anyone know how I would accomplish this?

Everything I have found so far from searching only works by listing out CSS for each level, and this would only work for a set number of submenus.

Comment: What have you tried? There are tons of tutorials/articles on this topic. Can you provide relevant HTML/CSS etc, demonstrating a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search led me to find this: http://dreaminpixels.co.uk/create-a-css-dropdown-with-unlimited-submenus-2/

Seems like it's just what you're looking for!

Comment: Not sure how I couldn't come across this :-/  Thanks very much for the quick answer, this works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to comment - here are some helpful links for making menus!

http://cssmenumaker.com/

http://www.cssmenusamples.com/

http://www.noupe.com/css/100-great-css-menu-tutorials.html

http://www.seoconsultants.com/css/menus/tutorial/